# Access to Instagram via Facebook Graph-API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I have an Instagram Business Account connected to a Facebook Page. When I try to access Instagram via the Graph-API I get an `Unsupported get request. Object with ID '{instagram account-id}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.`
The query I tried was (among others): `/v3.0/{insta-id}?fields=follow_count`

I tried personal- and page access tokens. What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: When you integrate a Facebook page with Instagram business account, it generates a new id for that Instagram business account. Are you using that id? If you are not using the new id, you can get that information by calling API /v3.0/me?fields=instagram_business_account

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (insights) on node type (InstagramUser)``

Comment: Can you please share the details of the curl / REST API what you are using?

Comment: Got "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (instagram_business_account) on node type (User)" when trying                       /v3.0/me?fields=instagram_business_account

Comment: @DowntheStream You should be able to fetch the instagram_business_account on the node accounts not user. Please try this /v3.0/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account

Answer (score 0):

What's interesting is that in your message you used {instagram account-id} to replace a numeric value that you saw in Facebook response. This number IS NOT your Instagram ID (as in your ID on Instagram). This number is Facebook's Instagram Business ID. It goes like this:

Facebook page (facebook page id) is associated with an Instagram Profile (instagram id) via Instagram Business Account (instagram business id).

In your above message, that ID is "instagram business id".

Why would it be missing? It is important how it was created: Instagram user, on their device, converted their Instagram account to Instagram Business account. When they did the selected a facebook page. This created "instagram business id".

If this user ever loses admin access to the Facebook page (or becomes anything other then admin) - "instagram business id" will become invalid.

How to fix? Simple, go to your device, convert your instagram profile to personal and then convert it back to business. You will get a new "instagram business id" so you will need to query that on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following request

me?fields=instagram_business_account - »

By this in the response you will get the business page id on that node you can make severall request.

*For instance*

{id}/media?fields=caption,like_count,comments_count,media_url